# WYSIWYG redactor with normal pasting

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

When i trying to paste some text from Word or Notepad to my WYSIWYG redactor (imperavi), it allocates every new line with `<p></p>` tags. Is it possible to configure it to mark new line with just `<br/>`?
I've tried with other redactors, but in every the same thing happens: new line in notepad - new paragraph in redactor.

(Browser: safari)

In FireFox everything is OK. New line - `<br/>`

Comment: Why is this question tagged with 'tinymce' when it is about 'redactor'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you need to set the configuration:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '' // Needed for 3.x
});
```